# Using the "swipe to go back" gesture in my own app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swipe, gestures

I'm building an iOS application that requires the same effect seen when swiping back and forth in Safari.

When swiping to go back, the foreground panel moves out of the way but the panel in the back is moving a bit as well. Very similar to the horizontal scrolling that exists in the Yahoo Weather app.

Is this a built-in control with iOS 7?  I'm seeing it in a lot of places but can't quite figure out how to do it.

Comment: This is standard behavior when using `UINavigationController`.

Comment: I see going back is standard ... But what about forward?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 `UIScrollView` working together, when the user scrolls on the foreground `UIScrollView`, you should move the background `UIScrollView`, something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if ([scrollView isEqual:self.scrollViewForeground]) {

        CGPoint offset = self.scrollViewForeground.contentOffset;
        offset.x = offset.x * 0.5;
        [self.scrollViewBackground setContentOffset:offset];
    }
}
```